# awk, calculate count from tabular data

Tags: arrays, awk, count, frequency

I have some tabular data where first field is a unique id and the second an observation like:

```
1   2
2   2
3   5
4   3
5   2
6   2
```

How can I use awk to calculate the frequency of the second field. In the example to get (observation count) :

```
2   4
3   1
5   1
```

I do not know which observations occurs before hand (i.e. 0, 1 and 4 does not occur in the example). I though I needed to make an associative array where entries could added and values increased by 1 when observations found but I really (honestly) did not know how to do this ?

Comment: Oops, you forgot to post your code! StackOverflow is about helping people fix their code. It's not a free coding service. Any code is better than no code at all. Meta-code, even, will demonstrate how you're thinking a program should work, even if you don't know how to write it.

Comment: Yeah I know - I really had embarrassing difficulties just getting started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '{cnt[$2]++} END{for (i in cnt) print i, cnt[i]}' file
2 4
3 1
5 1
```

The output order above is actually random due to the `in` operator. If you'd like to control that then with GNU awk you just set the order before entering the loop (see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Controlling-Scanning). For example:

To sort by numerically ascending array indices (the fact it is the same order as the above is coincidence):

```
$ awk '{cnt[$2]++} END{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"; for (i in cnt) print i, cnt[i]}' file
2 4
3 1
5 1
```

To sort by numerically ascending array values:

```
$ awk '{cnt[$2]++} END{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_asc"; for (i in cnt) print i, cnt[i]}' file
3 1
5 1
2 4
```

Comment: Ah really nice - I will have to study awk's arrays. I had something in pseudocode-mind.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

```
cat file.txt | awk '{
    dict[$2]++;
}
END {
    for (key in dict) { print key, dict[key] }
}'
```

Answer (score 1):

With `perl` it is a little easier to sort the keys into the order you present:

```
$ perl -lane '$seen{$F[1]}++; END{ for (sort keys %seen){ print "$_ $seen{$_}"}}' file
2 4
3 1
5 1
```

Or if you want to sort by frequency:

```
$ perl -lane '$seen{$F[1]}++; END{ for (sort {$seen{$a} <=> $seen{$b}} keys %seen){ print "$_ $seen{$_}"}}' file
3 1
5 1
2 4
```

(Reverse `$a` and `$b` if you want descending frequency vs ascending frequency...)

Comment: You can do the same trivially in GNU awk by just defining the sort order `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]=...` before looping using the `in` operator, see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Controlling-Scanning for predefined sort orders. I updated [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43850931/1745001) to show that.